# Building SQL query from information from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I am trying to create a query where I select information based on a separate table, but it says that I have invalid column names when I try to set the variables.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

DECLARE @c VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @c = COLUMN_NAME
SET @t = TABLE_NAME
SET @v = 'value'
SET @s = '['+@c+'] from ['+@t+'] where ['+@c+'] = ['+@v+']'

SELECT @s
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is SQL Server, I have updated the tags to show this. But I guess that is my question and will look into that.

Comment: You are probably looking for [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql?view=sql-server-2017). But beware: this looks like you're about to fall into the trap of [the inner platform effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).